# Add result in new column depending on old one

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I am comparing the tow release and sort the results as in the picture. The new functionalities in the release 2 with communities that uses these functionalities and the percentage of their PNR. I need to add in the column P the sum of the percentage like for the functionality plus percentage of their PNRS. Then we will have : "total percentage:37.97 % "

This is the code i am using if someone can help me :

```
Sub essai()
    Dim verif As Range, m As Range, dico As New Dictionary
    x = Sheets(1).Range("C4:C" & Sheets(1).Range("C:C").End(xlDown).Row).Count
    y = Sheets(1).Range("I4:I" & Sheets(1).Range("I:I").End(xlDown).Row).Count

    For j = 3 To y + 3
    If Not dico.Exists(Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value) Then
        dico.Add Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value, Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value
        PNRt = PNRt + Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value
    End If
    Next j

    For j = 3 To y + 3

    a = Sheets(1).Range("O1:O" & Sheets(1).Range("O:O").End(xlDown).Row).Count + 1

    Set m = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(3, 3), Sheets(1).Cells(x + 3, 3)).Find(Sheets(1).Cells(j, 9).Value)

    If m Is Nothing Then
    PNR = 1 - (PNRt - Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value) / PNRt

    PNR = Format(PNR, "0.00%")
    Set verif = Sheets(1).Range("N:N").Find(Sheets(1).Cells(j, 9).Value)

   If verif Is Nothing Then
        Sheets(1).Cells(a, 14).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 9).Value
        texte = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 7).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 8).Value & ", pourcentage PNR : " & PNR
        Sheets(1).Cells(a, 15).Value = texte

    Else
        texte = Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row, 15).Value
        texte = texte & "; " & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 7).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 8).Value & ", pourcentage PNR : " & PNR
        Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row, 15).Value = texte

    End If

    End If
    Next j
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line

```
PNR = 1 - (PNRt - Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value) / PNRt
```

add

```
PNR_VAL = PNR
```

---

```
If verif Is Nothing Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(a, 14).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 9).Value
    texte = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 7).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 8).Value & ", pourcentage PNR : " & PNR
    Sheets(1).Cells(a, 15).Value = texte
    Sheets(1).Cells(a,16).value = PNR_VAL
    Sheets(1).Cells(a,17).value = 1
Else
    if Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,17) < 5 then
        texte = Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row, 15).Value
        texte = texte & "; " & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 7).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(j, 8).Value & ", pourcentage PNR : " & PNR
        Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row, 15).Value = texte
    end if
    Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,16).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,16).Value + PNR_VAL
    Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,17).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,17).Value+1
End If
```

This should work

Comment: Hello @MutjayLee and thank you for your answer , i tried what you told me but what it does is showing the PNR in columns P i want to show the sum of them for that functionality

Comment: Did you add code "Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,16).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(verif.Row,16).Value + PNR after" after else?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I found out that Once PNR's format changed, it becomes string not number, and that cannot be added. I created separate variable called PNR_VAL and that will be able to add, and become sum when code is done.

Comment: Thanks so much MutjayLee it works perfect , i have just one question is it possible to show just the first five communities for each functionality

Comment: Thanks for marking "answered". And Yes, it is possible, but you will need separate counter.

Comment: can you please help me in this last one i understand what you said but i don't know how aplly it in the code ,

Comment: Your code basically writes on column "P" when it's the first one, and second one found, it will grab corresponding column "P" value, then increase it with additional percentage.  If you do same thing on let's say column "Q" and just have line check  **if Cells(verif.Row,17) <=5 then ** write values. If this makes sense :)

Comment: Ok i really appreciate your help

Comment: I've updated the answer. See how it works, and if that's what you want. Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: Oh, by the way, The code "x = Sheets(1).Range("C4:C" & Sheets(1).Range("C:C").End(xlDown).Row).Count" can be written as "x=Sheets(1).range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row". The difference is if there is blank within the data, xlDown will get the row number before the blank. and Rows.Count xlUp will find the very last one including blank datas.

Comment: Yes i agree with you this is much better but when i used the new version of code that you provided me , i had some problems it does show just the 5 communities but the total percentage is not on percentage format it's like this 0.8921  what could be the problem while the firs time it worked perfectly

Comment: You can either right click the Colum "P" > "Format Cells" > change to percentage format, or in the beginning of the code (not inside of loop) you can type Sheets(1).Columns("P").Numberformat = "0.00%"

Comment: it worked thanks , MutjayLee for the senario of showing just the first five communities the others the code do not take them in consideration ??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by taking them in consideration.

Comment: The way it works is when column "P" has 5 datas, then even it finds the next one, it will not write it. but you are still going through the loop and check them. You are just not displaying them. So for example, if you change **5** in Elseif line to **10**, it will display 10. if this answers your question...

Comment: ah so it will calculate the percentage for all communities that uses this functionality but it will not show them ? it will show just the first 5

Comment: Yes, the percentage it self is being calculated. But calculated percentage will be written over by next percentage calculation without displaying it or adding it to the sum.

Comment: aah what if we want to add it to the sum is it doable ??

Comment: I mean even if the other communities do not show in the results can we calculate their poucentage and add it to the sum

Comment: I've updated the answer again. This should just display first 5 communities, but it will calculate all percentages